# Получение относительной ссылки из URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется такая строка(URL), например:

```
'https://khashtamov.com/ru/?page=2'
```

Необходимо получить из неё относительную ссылку, то есть:

```
'/ru/?page=2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ограничения на стандартную библиотеку нет, рекомендую [`yarl`](https://pypi.org/project/yarl/):

```
In [2]: yarl.URL('https://khashtamov.com/ru/?page=2').path_qs
Out[2]: '/ru/?page=2'
```

Отличная библиотека для работы с гиперссылками от авторов `aiohttp`.

Comment: Отличный вариант!

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Рад был помочь!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, Вам поможет `urllib.parse`.

*Пример:*

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit


url = 'https://khashtamov.com/ru/?page=2'
parsed_url = urlsplit(url)

path = parsed_url.path + '?' + parsed_url.query

print(path)
```

*stdout:*

```html
/ru/?page=2
```

Comment: А возможен ли вариант более универсальный, при котором не нужно добавлять '?' ?

Comment: @Meltdown Искал пол часа, так ничего и не нашёл, увы... Если Вам удастся найти более хороший вариант, напишите, пожалуйста :)